# Error message when using two glossaries

Tags: glossaries

This looks like a trivial question. Here's part of my code:

```
\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,sort=use]{glossaries-extra}
\makenoidxglossaries
\newglossary*{gloss}{Glossary}
\newglossaryentry{gls:keyword1}{type=gloss,name=keyword1, description={just testing}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Density attached to $F$}]{f(x)}{\ensuremath{f(x)}}

\begin{document}
inserting a glossary entry in gloss: \gls{gloss:keyword1} \\
inserting a glossary entry in main glossary: $\gls{F(x)}$ \\

\printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,style=long,title={List of Symbols}] 
\printnoidxglossary[type=gloss,style=long,title={Glossary}]
\end{document}
```

If I remove "\gls{gloss:keyword1}", it works: the glossary "gloss" is not produced at all (it would be blank anyway) and the main glossary is nicely created under the title "List of Symbols". If I add
"\gls{gloss:keyword1}", it crashes, no output is produced, and the error message is

```
! Package glossaries-extra Error: Glossary entry `gloss:keyword1' has not been 
defined.

See the glossaries-extra package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.168 ...ng a glossary entry \gls{gloss:keyword1}
```

I read section 6 about multiple glossaries in what seems to be the reference on this subject,
*The glossaries package v4.49: a guide for beginners*, by Nicola L.C. Talbot ([here](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf), dated November 2021), but could not get it to work, after about two hours of trial and errors.

Comment: don't show only a "part of your code". Show a complete example that demonstrates your problem, that makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: beside this: you are defining `gls:keyword1` and `f(x)`, so you should use `\gls{gls:keyword1}` and `\gls{f(x)}`.

Comment: @Ulrike: I will provide a complete example next time I ask a question. I made the change you suggested, now it works!